# TableView columns position and TabbedPane tabs start from Right Side instead of left in JavaFX?

Tags: tableview, javafx-8

i've been searching for hours and could not find any way to make the tableView columns and tabs of a TabbedPane start from the right side instead of left.
As we can see in the picture java by default create them from the left side to the right, and leave empty space on the right side. Is there any way to do this vice versa ? 
Thank you
[see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVbUy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);`

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.NodeOrientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class NodeOrientationTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        tabPane.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        Tab tab1 = new Tab("Tab 1");
        Tab tab2 = new Tab("Tab 2");
        tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tab1, tab2);

        TableView<Void> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        table.getColumns().add(new TableColumn<Void, Void>("Column 1"));
        table.getColumns().add(new TableColumn<Void, Void>("Column 2"));

        tab1.setContent(table);

        Scene scene = new Scene(tabPane, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Note that the table view will, by default, inherit this from its parent, so you can omit the call to `table.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);` and achieve the same result. (Or just set it on the scene.)